# BlocBuilder doesn't builds view respects to bluetooth state

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am trying to show the current bluetooth state (on, off, loading) in the screen. When i debugged, everything seems true. Code executes every if I wanted to execute. Still shows nothing in UI. Used `flutter_blue` package.

`bluetooth_cubit_dart.`:

```
part 'bluetooth_state.dart';

class BluetoothCubit extends Cubit<BluetoothCubitState> {
  final FlutterBlue flutterBlue;
  late final StreamSubscription bluetoothStreamSubscription;

  BluetoothCubit({required this.flutterBlue}) : super(BluetoothStateLoading()) {
    monitorBluetooth();
  }

  StreamSubscription<BluetoothState> monitorBluetooth() {
    return bluetoothStreamSubscription = flutterBlue.state.listen((state) {
      print("flutter_ble package streams $state");
      if (state == BluetoothState.turningOn || state == BluetoothState.on) {
        print("Cubit inside if statement $state");
        emitBluetoothOn();
      } else if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
        print("Inside if statement $state");
        emitBluetoothOff();
      } else if (state == BluetoothState.unknown) {
        print("Inside if statement $state");
        emitBluetoothStateLoading();
      }
    });
  }

  void emitBluetoothOn() {
    emit(BluetoothStateOn());
  }

  void emitBluetoothOff() {
    emit(BluetoothStateOff());
  }

  void emitBluetoothStateLoading() {
    emit(BluetoothStateLoading());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    bluetoothStreamSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

`bluetooth_state.dart`:

```
part of 'bluetooth_cubit.dart';

abstract class BluetoothCubitState {}

class BluetoothStateOn extends BluetoothCubitState {}

class BluetoothStateOff extends BluetoothCubitState {}

class BluetoothStateLoading extends BluetoothCubitState {}
```

`main.dart`:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp(
    appRouter: AppRouter(),
    connectivity: Connectivity(),
    flutterBlue: FlutterBlue.instance,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final AppRouter appRouter;
  final Connectivity connectivity;
  final FlutterBlue flutterBlue;

  const MyApp(
      {Key? key,
      required this.appRouter,
      required this.connectivity,
      required this.flutterBlue})
      : super(key: key);
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<InternetCubit>(
          create: (context) => InternetCubit(connectivity: connectivity),
        ),
        BlocProvider<CounterCubit>(
          create: (context) => CounterCubit(
              internetCubit: BlocProvider.of<InternetCubit>(context)),
        ),
        BlocProvider<BluetoothCubit>(
          create: (context) => BluetoothCubit(flutterBlue: flutterBlue),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Bloc Basics',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        onGenerateRoute: appRouter.myOnGenerateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A part of `home_screen.dart`:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: widget.color,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: BlocBuilder<BluetoothCubit, BluetoothCubitState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is BluetoothStateOn) {
                    print("BlocBuilder inside if statement $state");
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: const [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.bluetooth,
                          color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        ),
                        Text("Bluetooth Connected")
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (state is BluetoothStateOff) {
                    print("BlocBuilder inside if statement $state");
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: const [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.bluetooth,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text("Bluetooth Disconnected")
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (state is BluetoothStateLoading) {
                    print("BlocBuilder inside if statement $state");
                    return Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: const [
                        CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        Text("Bluetooth State Loading")
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                },
              ),
            ),
```

And the ***Debug console*** shows:

```
Restarted application in 2,157ms.
I/flutter (18520): BlocBuilder inside if statement Instance of 'BluetoothStateLoading'
D/HwCustConnectivityManagerImpl(18520): isBlockNetworkRequestByNonAis, INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
D/ConnectivityManager(18520): requestNetwork and the calling app is: com.example.bloc_basics
I/flutter (18520): flutter_ble package streams BluetoothState.on
I/flutter (18520): Cubit inside if statement BluetoothState.on
I/flutter (18520): BlocBuilder inside if statement Instance of 'BluetoothStateOn'
```

Couldn't figure out what's wrong. By the way I wonder if my way of handling state is best practice.

Comment: Turns out I forget ```return``` before rows ..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forget return before rows ..

old:

```
if (state is BluetoothStateOn) {
                    print("BlocBuilder inside if statement $state");
                    Row(
```

now:

```
if (state is BluetoothStateOn) {
                    print("BlocBuilder inside if statement $state");
                    return Row(
```

Comment: Consider removing the question as it's a too-general syntax error (missing return).

Comment: It says if you delete post your account may be blocked from asking